# Read files from folder in php and list out entries from json file

Tags: php, json

I am trying to load in all of the images within a folder using php and then build out a table and pull text from a json file and put it next to each image. The goal is to have json that looks like this.

```
{
    "Car1": {
        "year":"2012"
    },
    "Car2": {
        "year":"2011"
    },
    "Car3": {
        "year":"2009",
        "milage":"10,204"
    }
}
```

The Car1, Car2 names will ultimately match the names of the actual images in the folder as well. So i want to grab the image and the correct section in the json file and build out a table listing them all out. So far i have the below php, but am not really sure how to put it all together, as you can see below, its just separate right now. Any suggestions on how to combine the php below to achieve the result i described?

---

6/1 Edit (New Code using answer below). This is on a page in the spot where i want all of this outputted and the &letter variable is passed from a form on another page. But when that form submits and this page fires off, nothing happens. Am i doing something incorrect?

```
$letter = $_POST['letter'];

//Call the path of the cars for the chosen letter
$path = "/images/PartsCars/".$letter."/";
$temp_files = scandir($path);

//Call the path for the json file in the chosen letter subfolder
$data = json_decode($string, true);

//Sort the pictures in this folder alphabetically
natsort($temp_files);

echo '<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';

//Loop through all pictures and json elements to build out the page
foreach($temp_files as $file) 
{
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "Thumbs.db" && $file != basename(__FILE__)) 
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.$url.$file.'" title="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$url.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'" style="width:300px;height:200px;"/></a></td>';
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        $file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
        echo '<td>'.print_r($data['$file_name']).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using php json_decode for ease of use and using print_r to demo, you could use a foreach loop to print it out properly

```
$path = "./images/PartsCars/A/";
$temp_files = scandir($path);
$string = file_get_contents("/images/PartsCars/A/sample.json");
data = json_decode($string, true);

natsort($temp_files);

echo "<table>";

foreach($temp_files as $file) 
{
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "Thumbs.db" && $file != basename(__FILE__)) 
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.$url.$file.'" title="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$url.$file.'" alt="" /></a></td>';
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        $file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
        echo '<td>'.print_r(data['$file_name']).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>'
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Please see my edit above as i think there is still something i am missing.